# How can I get my Web browser in MacOS to use dnsmasq?

Tags: macos

I've started dnsmasq with synth-domain option so I can resolve AWS EC2 hostnames on my MacOS Ventura 13.1:

```
$ ps -ef |grep [d]nsma
   -2 12576     1   0  7:19AM ??         0:00.01 dnsmasq --listen-address=127.0.0.1 --synth-domain=us-west-2.compute.internal,172.16.0.0/12,ip-
$
```

I've updated /etc/resolv.conf to put that DNS server first:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep -v ^#
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
$
```

I also updated my Network settings for my wi-fi connection in the Settings control panel to have the same DNS order.

I can lookup an A record:

```
$ host -t a ip-172-24-31-194.us-west-2.compute.internal
ip-172-24-31-194.us-west-2.compute.internal has address 172.24.31.194
$
```

But if I try to SSH or curl, I strike out:

```
$ curl ip-172-24-31-194.us-west-2.compute.internal
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ip-172-24-31-194.us-west-2.compute.internal
$ ssh ip-172-24-31-194.us-west-2.compute.internal
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ip-172-24-31-194.us-west-2.compute.internal: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
$
```

Same deal with Google Chrome or Firefox, it fails DNS lookup.

What black magic is happening here?  How can I get my Web browser and command-line utilities to use dnsmasq's synth domain?

---

Update:

`scutil --dns` shows:

```
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  nameserver[0] : 127.0.0.1
  nameserver[1] : 8.8.8.8
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00030002 (Reachable,Local Address,Directly Reachable Address)

resolver #2
  domain   : local
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300000

resolver #3
  domain   : 254.169.in-addr.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300200

resolver #4
  domain   : 8.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300400

resolver #5
  domain   : 9.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300600

resolver #6
  domain   : a.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300800

resolver #7
  domain   : b.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 301000

DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  nameserver[0] : 127.0.0.1
  nameserver[1] : 8.8.8.8
  if_index : 7 (en0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00000002 (Reachable)
```

Comment: macOS's DNS resolver subsystem uses the SystemConfiguration database as its source of truth, and autogenerates `/etc/resolv.conf` after the fact for the sake of any legacy Unix utils that rely on their own DNS resolver code (e.g. `host`, `dig`, `nslookup`, etc.). So any time you are troubleshooting DNS on macOS, you need to use `scutil` (the "SystemConfiguration Utility") to see what DNS settings the system is really using. Please edit your question to include the output of `scutil --dns`.

Comment: Also note that some DNS resolver implementations don't consider the list of DNS server address to be an ordered/ranked list. Some implementations consider it an unranked (equally-weighted) pool of available DNS servers and may choose to do a kind of round-robin load balancing across all DNS server addresses in the list. So if you always want all queries to go to a certain DNS server (such as `dnsmasq` running on localhost), you need it to be the ONLY DNS server address your system knows about (`dnsmasq` itself gets to privately know about other upstream DNS servers via `dnsmasq.conf`).

Answer (score 0):

As @Spiff suggested, I changed the DNS server list in the Network settings control panel to the dnsmasq server only (127.0.0.1) and then restarted `dnsmasq` telling it to use Google public DNS as its upstream server:

```
sudo dnsmasq --listen-address=127.0.0.1 --synth-domain=us-west-2.compute.internal,172.16.0.0/12,ip- --server=8.8.8.8
```

I can now resolve AWS EC2 hostnames in the us-west-2.compute.internal domain and real-world DNS hostnames like superuser.com.  Thanks!